# SQLSRV_QUERY omitting WHERE condition

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a query that returns 10 rows, but when I put the WHERE condition in only returns 8 rows in SQL Server, which is fine! But when I try to do this on PHP I'm getting 10 rows instead of 8, so for some reason it's not "reading" the WHERE condition, and I don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
$conn = $this->ConnectToDatabase();
$query = "SELECT P.NAME FROM PEOPLE P WHERE P.SPECIAL_CHARACTER IN ('*', 'X')";
$temp = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
$result = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $temp, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC )) {
   array_push($result, $row);
}
return $result;
```

So when I do that, I'm getting the information of 10 rows instead of 8, so for some reason it's omitting the `WHERE P.SPECIAL_CHARACTER IN ('*', 'X')`, which is weird.

That's my issue. That query should be returning 8 rows, which it does in SQL Server, but when I try to do it from PHP it returns 10, and I don't know why, I don't see anything weird in the WHERE.

Comment: Are you sure PHP is connecting to the same server and database that you're querying in (presumably) SSMS?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yeah, it is..I can make like 20 different queries and they are going to work fine, but for some reason that query is not working.

Comment: Same user credentials as well? i.e.: Could [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) be involved?

Comment: So what else have you done to debug? What happens when you have only `*` or `X`, what if you do `not in` etc

Comment: Update your `SELECT` list (in the program) to show the primary key and the special_character column, so you can verify the data in these extra rows really contain the data you didn't expect.  Now test that same SQL outside your program in an effort to find the differences.